# UsernameNotFoundException thrown as 403 in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project. When a request is made with incorrect user credentials :

```
catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        log.error("Error occurred while fetching user {}: {}", securityPrincipal, ex);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user: " + securityPrincipal);
    }
```

But the exception thrown finally is a 500.

After going through a number of links I found that :

```
 protected AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter multiPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() throws Exception {

        MultiPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter filter = new MultiPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter();

        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setPreAuthenticatedPrincipalProviders(preAuthenticatedPrincipalProviders);
        filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
        filter.setInvalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange(true);
        filter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(**true**);

        return filter;
    }
```

Changing continueFilterChainOnUnsuccesfulAuthentication to true would help throw the Authentication exception as is. But after this was changed as true, the UsernameNotFoundException is thrown as a 403 instead of a 401.

Is there some basic security configuration that is missing?

Comment: Did you get the answer for this ?

Comment: @Scooby - Nope. Nothing yet.

Comment: if you really need to throw 401 why dont you create a exceptionHandler with @controllerAdvice and throw what ever status code you need. this link has all the details https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @Grinish - I'm throwing this exception in UserDetailsProvider, an exception thrown here, apparently does not go through the Controller advice, but is handled by the security filter chain.Because of this I'm facing this issue.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Serving a 403 instead of a 401 is absolutely correct according to the HTTP specs cause credentials have been provided and are not correct. Returning a 401 would indicate that the user should specify access credentials.

See:

- [wikipedia article of HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

**UPDATE**

Actually this is not 100% clear cause [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) says that 401 **may** be returned if the credentials provided are incorrect.